# Firebase database child values are null while retrieving

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve the database values, but the data in child which I fetched using uID is null.

[image]

Here is my code-

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
                        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                        currentUser = extras.getString("currentUser");
                        selectedUser = extras.getString("selectedUser");
                        uID = extras.getString("uID");
                mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


            mDbReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                final DatabaseReference uidRef = mDbReference.child("users").child(uID);

                ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                DataSnapshot firstChild = ds.child(ChatMessageModel.MSG_TYPE_RECEIVED);
                for (DataSnapshot secondChild : firstChild.getChildren()) {
                    ChatMessageModel chatMessageModel = secondChild.getValue(ChatMessageModel.class);
                    messageList.add(chatMessageModel);
                    for (int i = 0; i < messageList.size(); i++) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "All received messages : " + messageList.get(i).getMsgContent());

                    }
                }

            }
                            chatAppMsgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
                        }
                    };
                    uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

//and here is my database
u0TddklO8BXKCRHp4UFXEvmPS1H3: null //u0TddklO8BXKCRHp4UFXEvmPS1H3 is uid. where, uid is of currentuser.
//ans must be -

```
  "users": {
           "User2" : {
  "MSG_TYPE_RECEIVED" : {
    "-LNEG2DhamuO6hAvZUp9" : {
      "msgContent" : "hello",
      "msgType" : "MSG_TYPE_RECEIVED"
    },
    "-LNEG8hxAcXp05g5RYly" : {
      "msgContent" : "Hi fi",
      "msgType" : "MSG_TYPE_RECEIVED"
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: code seems fine , check your node js code

Comment: are you sure u0TddklO8BXKCRHp4UFXEvmPS1H3 key is present on firebase?

Comment: add screenshot of your firebase database here , it seems there is no value for  "u0TddklO8BXKCRHp4UFXEvmPS1H3" in the node "users".

Comment: so  there is no value for "u0TddklO8BXKCRHp4UFXEvmPS1H3"  in 
"users": {
            "user1": {
              "MSG_TYPE_RECEIVED": {
                "-LMzfa7YtTRH3FjMwl4c": {
                  "msgContent": "Hello1",
                  "msgType": "MSG_TYPE_RECEIVED"
                }
              }

Comment: Hey, I have added screenshot of my database. Actually, u0TddklO8BXKCRHp4UFXEvmPS1H3 - this string is the uid of User2. which I got using currentUser.getuid(). It refers to the User2 in database. I want to fetch RECEIVED_MESSAGES of User2 only.

Answer (score 0):

as understood from your comment 
the database which is like this

```
"users": {
           "User2" : {
  "MSG_TYPE_RECEIVED" : {
    "-LNEG2DhamuO6hAvZUp9" : {
      "msgContent" : "hello",
      "msgType" : "MSG_TYPE_RECEIVED"
    },
    "-LNEG8hxAcXp05g5RYly" : {
      "msgContent" : "Hi fi",
      "msgType" : "MSG_TYPE_RECEIVED"
    }
  }
```

change your database into

```
"users": {
           "u0TddklO8BXKCRHp4UFXEvmPS1H3" : {
  "MSG_TYPE_RECEIVED" : {
    "-LNEG2DhamuO6hAvZUp9" : {
      "msgContent" : "hello",
      "msgType" : "MSG_TYPE_RECEIVED"
    },
    "-LNEG8hxAcXp05g5RYly" : {
      "msgContent" : "Hi fi",
      "msgType" : "MSG_TYPE_RECEIVED"
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Its not working. bcz at the time of sending messages I don't have uid of receiver/selected user. So while sending, above code is possible but at the receiver side its not working.

Comment: so if u don't have the user ID while sending It is not possible to get the data without knowing the key .
but if you need to change the code of uID = extras.getString("uID"); to return "User2" instead of u0TddklO8BXKCRHp4UFXEvmPS1H3 .